# ionic2 app not able to run on internet explorer

Tags: ionic2

I created a sample ionic 2 App which works perfectly on Chrome and Android Browser, but when I tried it on Internet Explorer It giving me below error.

```
>EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError
>EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError
>STACKTRACE:
>Error: Uncaught (in promise): SyntaxError
>at resolvePromise (http://localhost/build/js/angular2-polyfills.js:602:26)
>at Anonymous function (http://localhost/build/js/angular2-polyfills.js:638:18)
>at ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask
```

While Angular 2 sample project is working fine on Internet Explore why there is a difference in IONIC 2 build , UI issue is fine but at least it should run the App without breaking.

Comment: Having the same problem right now... :( Have you been able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I just found this official post on the Ionic forum saying that Ionic 2 doesn't support Internet Explorer, only Edge: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-sample-app-not-working-on-internet-explore/50283/2

No idea though if this will change for future releases, but I wouldn't count on it... Time to say goodbye to IE, finally ;)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to render IONIC 2 on Internet Explolrer 10.

In order to install the proper polyfills do this:

> npm install core-js --save

Then in your app class import it

> import 'core-js';

It worked for me with core-js version 2.4.1 on Ionic 2 beta 10, Angular 2.0.0-rc.3 .

Answer (score 0):

On my computer it looks like IE opens the ionic application in Compatibility Mode by default.

After you disable Compatibility Mode the pages will work fine.